# How do I make my background image crop down when I'm resizing the web page?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

Right now when I resize my background image, it does not distort the image size (which is good), but it doesn't crop it either. For example, my background image is a banner at the top of the page with a graphic on the left side. When I drag my window from the left towards the right, the graphic maintains it's position to the left of the screen. I'd like the image (as well as all of my website content) to be cropped when I resize the image. (So that the browser doesn't try and fit all the content (including the header) on the now-smaller page.)

This is my css code for the background image

```
body {
background-image: url("images/header.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; }
```

Also note: All of my content will be centered on the web page -- if this helps with anything.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Have you tried `background-size:cover;`? Don't forget vender prefixes :)

Comment: Hmm, didn't work yet.

Comment: Updated my answer. I'm a little confused. If you want the background image to fill up the entire body then use background-size cover. As far as the page not resizing, just set the width of body and html to 100%. To center the image use background-position:center center;

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
background-image: url("images/header.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-size: cover; 
}
```

Comment: Seriously dude? You stole my answer! You won't make it on stack overflow by doing that.

Comment: Hi Thanks so much for your answer, but background size cover really just makes the background image fill up my entire web page which is not it's intended use.

Comment: @www139 - don't you hate it when that happens??  You could always [flag it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258558/how-to-deal-with-a-stolen-answer#answer-258835)

Comment: @www139 This answer was posted five minutes before yours.

Comment: My comment was posted 3 minutes before this answer (on the question). I am starting to find stackoverflow a little too competitive for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

```
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body {
    background-image:url("images/header.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle for you :) https://jsfiddle.net/www139/5wqp3622/

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer - but it didn't work. It made the small image fill my whole web page. The results were also the same whether I used  a vendor prefix or not.